# Is it possible to create an object expression at runtime?

Tags: f#

If a user passes in an interface, and I want to dynamically make a class out of it, is it possible to do so using an object expression? That is, given an interface:

```
type IMyInterface =
    abstract Perform : Unit -> Unit
```

is there some way to say:

```
obj = {
    new IMyInterface with
        member this.Perform() = Console.WriteLine("Perform this action")
}
```

If not, is there a non-Reflection.Emit way of doing that?

Comment: Awesome, didn't know F# had a code-dom. Thanks

Comment: The F# mocking framework (Foq) does that using Reflection Emit (I think), so if you want to follow that path, you can check out the source (there might even be some reusable component for that): https://foq.codeplex.com/

Comment: I ended up just going the Reflection.Emit route. I'll definitely take a look at that though.